# Uniform Topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma} $ is different from Product Topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma}$

Tags: general-topology

This question is from My topology assignment and i was unable to solve it and unfortunately I have no intution on how this question should be approached.

> Question:If $\Gamma$ is an infinite set then prove that Uniform Topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma} $ is different from Product   Topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma}$.

Definition of uniform Topology: Let $\Gamma$ be a non empty set and let $\bar{d}$ be the standard bounded metric on $\mathbb{R}$ . Define a metric $\bar{\mathbb{\rho}}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma}$ by  $\bar{\mathbb{\rho}}(x,y)$= {lub${\bar{d}(x_{\alpha} ,y_{\alpha})}: \alpha \in \Gamma$}.Then $ \bar{\mathbb{\rho}}$ is a metric called uniform metric and topology induced by $\bar{\mathbb{\rho}}$ is called uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\Gamma}$.

Can you please tell me on how should this question should be solved.  Also, I am really sorry that I would not be able to Get any attemp as I don't have anything worthy to show.

Thank you!

Comment: the uniform topology is finer than the product topology

Answer (score 1):

For each $\gamma\in\Gamma$, define $f_\gamma\colon\Gamma\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ as$$f_\gamma(\alpha)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }\alpha=\gamma\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Let $0\in\Bbb R^\Gamma$ be the null function. Then, for each $\gamma\in\Gamma$, $\overline\rho(f_\gamma,0)=\overline d(0,1)>0$. So, $0\notin\overline{\{f_\gamma\mid\gamma\in\Gamma\}}$.

However, with respect to the product topology on $\Bbb R^\Gamma$ we do have$$0\in\overline{\{f_\gamma\mid\gamma\in\Gamma\}}.\tag1$$In fact, if $A$ is an open set of $\Bbb R^\Gamma$ with respect to that topology and if $0\in A$, then, for some finite subset $F$ of $\gamma$, and for a set $\{(-\varepsilon_\gamma,\varepsilon_\gamma)\mid\gamma\in F\}$ of intervals of $\Bbb R$ (with each $\varepsilon_\gamma$ greater than $0$), $A$ contains the set$$\left\{f\in\Bbb R^\Gamma\,\middle|\,(\forall\gamma\in F):f(\gamma)\in(-\varepsilon_\gamma,\varepsilon_\gamma)\right\}.$$In particular, if $\gamma\in\Gamma\setminus F$, then $f_\gamma\in A$. So, since $\Gamma$ is infinite, $A$ contains some element of $\{f_\gamma\mid\gamma\in\Gamma\}$ (actually, infinitely many of them), and so we do have $(1)$.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. There are of course many other ways. E.g. by the Tychonoff Theorem, the subspace $T=[0,1]^{\Gamma}$ is compact in the Product Topology. But in the Uniform Topology, $T$ is not compact because it has an infinite closed discrete subspace $\{f_{\gamma}:\gamma \in \Gamma \}.$

Answer (score 0):

The "canonical" base (basis) $B_P$ for the Product Topology is the set of all $\prod_{g\in \Gamma} V_g$ such that (i) each $V_g$ is open in $\Bbb R,$ and (ii) $\{g\in \Gamma :V_g\ne \Bbb R\}$ is finite.

Let $U$ be an  open $\bar \rho$-ball of radius $1/3$ in the Uniform Topology. For some set $\{W_g: g\in \Gamma \}$ of non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R,$ we have $U\subseteq V=\prod_{g\in \Gamma}W_g$ where $\sup W_g -\inf W_g\le 2/3$ for each $g.$

No non-empty member of $B_P$ is a subset of $V.$ So $U$ is not a union of members of $B_P.$ So $U$ is not open in the Product Topology.